# Android In-App Billing get previous purchase token

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is it possible to receive a purchase token again? My intention is, that the client has a list of all token (for server side verfication), but after reinstalling the app my token are all gone.

I need it, because my server holds the purchases in the backend. I don't want to know the gmail-account on my server, but how can I connect the purchases with an unique id onto my server?

Comment: I found the token. I only need to call queryInventory from my helper class.